# How do I put a table and a figure in a minipage?

Tags: minipage

I am trying to put a figure beside a table using a minipage. Below is my table.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage   {lipsum}
\usepackage   {showframe} % just for this example
\usepackage   {subfig}
\usepackage   {tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{XX.}
\begin{tabular}{l|x{.3in}x{.3in}|x{.3in}x{.3in}|x{.3in}x{.3in}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{XX} \\
\textbf{Recognition} & Left & Right & Left & Right & Left & Right \\
\midrule
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textcolor{white}{1}} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{XX} \\
\textbf{Anticipation} & Left & Right & Left & Right & Left & Right \\
\midrule
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code with the minipage does not work. The table goes missing.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage   {lipsum}
\usepackage   {showframe} % just for this example
\usepackage   {subfig}
\usepackage   {tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{XX.}
\begin{tabular}{l|x{.3in}x{.3in}|x{.3in}x{.3in}|x{.3in}x{.3in}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{XX} \\
\textbf{Recognition} & Left & Right & Left & Right & Left & Right \\
\midrule
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textcolor{white}{1}} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{XX} \\
\textbf{Anticipation} & Left & Right & Left & Right & Left & Right \\
\midrule
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{caption below}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't place a floating environment such as  `table` inside of a `minipage`, do it the other way around and place the `minipages` inside of the `table`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage   {lipsum}
\usepackage   {showframe} % just for this example
\usepackage   {subfig}
\usepackage   {tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{XX.}
\begin{tabular}{l|x{.3in}x{.3in}|x{.3in}x{.3in}|x{.3in}x{.3in}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{XX} \\
\textbf{Recognition} & Left & Right & Left & Right & Left & Right \\
\midrule
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textcolor{white}{1}} \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{XX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{XX} \\
\textbf{Anticipation} & Left & Right & Left & Right & Left & Right \\
\midrule
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{caption below}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```